# Play event is going to infinite loop in videojs

Tags: javascript, html, video, html5-video, video.js

I just did a small example of videojs, which has a log on event play, and i am using APIs like **`play(),pause()`.**

```
var myplayer;
var playCount = 0;
videojs("example_video_1").ready(function(){

      myplayer = this;

      myplayer.on("play", function(){
        playCount++;
        $("#count").text(playCount)

      });

});
$("#test").click(function (){  
    myplayer.pause();
    myplayer.play();
});
```

The issue is that while executing the APIs the play event will go to an infinite loop.

I can found this issue in touch devices if I enable the controls even while seeking the bar, do play pause etc. So if I didnt use the combination also I can found this issues.
Internally the library is using these APIs in seek, or other controls ?

Link in jsfiddle **[LIVE BUG:](http://jsfiddle.net/vN28W/1/)**

Comment: Has this problem re-emerged in 4.3, at least in Firefox?? I'm getting looping in Firefox (but no other browsers) in my own projects, and an updated version of the above fiddle is, I believe, not working correctly: http://jsfiddle.net/vN28W/3/ ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug in video js event handling:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/573 <-- original bug

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/620 <-- best info on 'why' here

In the meantime, one workaround is to put any play/pause toggles in timeouts.

```
$("#test").click(function (){
    myplayer.pause();
    window.setTimeout(function() {myplayer.play();}, 10);
});
```

Comment: im getting this issue on seek,paly ,pause in touchdevices.. even though im not using the apis directly, internaly the library is using

Answer (score 1):

This is the fix forthis issue...
https://github.com/cameront/video.js/commit/ff0b443c285691074f7f01e8d0326ade0f0a6609  for issues/620